# Нахождение слова в тексте по маске

Tags: алгоритм, vb.net

Есть текст из нескольких тысяч слов, и в нем нужно найти все слова по маске.

Например: `"сл*в*"`... = `"слово"`

Как это сделать?

Comment: @Regent обычно его используют. Я предложил Miki если я не прав он может это удалить. Я хотел что бы вопрос был более полным.

Comment: @Regent согласен. тогда я лучше уберу поправку. Спасибо за совет

Comment: @Regent ок, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Тут можете сделать поточный поиск.

1. берете `charFromStream` - берете один символ из большой строки
2. берете `charInMask` - это текущий символ (в начале первый) маски
3. сопоставляете `charFromStream` с `charInMask` и если не равно двигаете `charFromStream` по тексту пока не будут равны.
4. Если оба равны пропускаете символы ? и * по маске из текста пока следующий символы не будут равны.
5. Если конец маски или не совпадение символов, берете `charInMask` из начало маски
6. проверяете до конца текста или до совпадения

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения.

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("file.txt")
Dim pattern As String = "\bсл.*?в.*?\b"
Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, options)

For Each word In matches
    Console.WriteLine(word)
Next
```

Здесь `\b` означает границу слова. `.*?` - ноль или больше любых символов, нежадно.